# Is there a way to use Flyway on AS400?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, flyway

I need to implement migration tool like Flyway in order to use Jenkins to deploy DB changes.
I tried to add jt400.jar file and added configuration as follows:

```
flyway.url=jdbc:as400://192.168.171.251:446/DBDEV
flyway.driver=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
```

as a driver and it would not connect with this message:

```
ERROR: No database found to handle jdbc:as400://192.168.171.251:446/DBDEV
```

I also tried with using IBM DB2 driver and had configuration

```
flyway.url=jdbc:db2://192.168.171.251:50000/DBDEV
flyway.driver=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

this time I am getting this kind of refusal message

```
ERROR: 
Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:db2://192.168.171.251:50000/DBDEV) for user 'DEVUSER': 
[jcc][t4][2043][11550][4.26.14] Exception java.net.ConnectException: Error opening socket to server
 /192.168.171.251 on port 50,000 with message: Connection refused (Connection refused). 
ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
```

With this test migration I am trying to create a simple table by executing this sql

```sql
CREATE TABLE PERSON (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

Anyone had this situation and solved it?

Comment: @mao thanks for suggestions.
I tried to use both ports 446 and 50000 on both driver and url configuration and it did not work, though, as400 works well when using DBClient such as DBeaver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that at present there is no support for flyway to work with IBM i (as/400) regardless of whether you use jt400.jar or an IBM jdbc driver.

You can either use a different database-schema versioning tool, or find a fork of flyway that supports i-series (or pay someone to create and support such a fork, it is open source...).

It seems that currently (`flyway 7.7.2`) does not recognize a URL that starts with `"jdbc:as400:"` as a Db2 URL, so it throws an exception, which is the reason that the `jt400.jar` style URL is rejected with exception:

> "No database found to handle ..."

The github history tells a story (see: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/105).

Looks like the devs did not succeed to get the AS400 support added due to the lack of a suitable available i-series testing/dev environment (and also available to travis ci) . There may have been at least one PR for such support in the past, although it seems to be removed.

If you try to use the IBM db2jcc4.jar driver to connect to i-series (as400) with a url similar to: `jdbc:db2://hostname/dbname`, and you explicitly use an IBM jre , and have the relevant license file (e.g. db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar on the CLASSPATH), then flyway will connect and then report the exception similar to:

> Unsupported Database: AS 7.4

The flyway source code shows that flyway does not recognize this database product-name and version, at current flyway version 7.7.2.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `DBDEV` is the name of your Db2 data base on the IBM i?

Use the Work with RDB Directory Entry (WRKRDBDIRE) from the green screen, and look for the *LOCAL entry.

Or use the Access Client Solutions (ACS) "Schemas" tool to see a list of DB on your system.
[image]

The above shows 2 DB's, `UT29p63` and `Dbtest`

Comment: Thank you for that.
I checked and I can see in IBM iAccess that is the only database.

Comment: try `flyway.url=jdbc:as400://192.168.171.251;Database=DBDEV` I don't think you need the port.